# Export Libgdx desktop to swf?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

So, I've been developing game using with Libgdx.,
The desktop project will produce an executable jar file.
Can we produce it to swf (flash game) file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

Libgdx wraps OpenGL, and can be ported to other OpenGL-based rendering systems (though this is [often convoluted and indirect](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/IOSWIP)).  SWF is not based on an OpenGL API, and so would require a bunch of emulation/API mangling in addition to converting Java into ActionScript.  I would say it is impossible, but the GWT and iOS ports of Libgdx exist and I would have thought those impossible too.

The [Libgdx GWT port](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2308) (which converts Libgdx Java source to Javascript and WebGL) might get you to a similar destination (a big blob that you stick on a webpage and users can interact with in their web browser).

Comment: OK thanks (y)
Hey, can I ask you something ?
I've downloaded android ADT, which contain eclipse.
Now, when I try to launch libgdx HTML, it always error about gwt.
I've tried quick fixing it, but not hlping at all.,
I think I've to download google gwt, but which one ? I don't even know the eclipse's version.,

Comment: You are probably missing the GWT.  Ask another question with the specific error messages you are seeing in the `Problems` view.